# Improve efficiency of selecting values from dataframe by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have a simulation that uses pandas Dataframes to describe objects in a hierarchy. To achieve this, I have used a MultiIndex to show the route to a child object.

**Parent df**

```
        par_val
a b            
0 0.0  0.366660
  1.0  0.613888
1 2.0  0.506531
  3.0  0.327356
2 4.0  0.684335
  0.0  0.013800
3 1.0  0.590058
  2.0  0.179399
4 3.0  0.790628
  4.0  0.310662
```

**Child df**

```
          child_val
a b   c           
0 0.0 0   0.528217
  1.0 0   0.515479
1 2.0 0   0.719221
  3.0 0   0.785008
2 4.0 0   0.249344
  0.0 0   0.455133
3 1.0 0   0.009394
  2.0 0   0.775960
4 3.0 0   0.639091
  4.0 0   0.150854
0 0.0 1   0.319277
  1.0 1   0.571580
1 2.0 1   0.029063
  3.0 1   0.498197
2 4.0 1   0.424188
  0.0 1   0.572045
3 1.0 1   0.246166
  2.0 1   0.888984
4 3.0 1   0.818633
  4.0 1   0.366697
```

This implies that object (0,0,0) and (0,0,1) in the child Dataframes are both characterised by values at (0,0) in the parent Dataframe.

When a function is performed on the child dataframe for a certain subject of 'a', it may therefore need to grab a value from 'b'. My current solution locates the value from the parent Dataframe by index within the **solution** function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

r = range(10, 1000, 10)
dt = []
for i in r:
    start = time.time()

    df_par = pd.DataFrame(
        {'a': np.repeat(np.arange(5), i/5),
        'b': np.append(np.arange(i/2), np.arange(i/2)),
        'par_val': np.random.rand(i)
        }).set_index(['a','b'])

    df_child = pd.concat([df_par[[]]] * 2, keys = [0, 1], names = ['c'])\
        .reorder_levels(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    df_child['child_val'] = np.random.rand(i * 2)
    df_child['solution'] = np.nan

    def solution(row, df_par, var):
        data_level = len(df_par.index.names)
        index_filt = tuple([row.name[i] for i in range(data_level)])
        sol = df_par.loc[index_filt, 'par_val'] / row.child_val
        return sol



    a_mask = df_child.index.get_level_values('a') == 0

    df_child.loc[a_mask, 'solution'] = df_child.loc[a_mask].apply(solution,
                                                                  df_par = df_par,
                                                                  var = 10,
                                                                  axis = 1)
    stop = time.time()
    dt.append(stop - start)

plt.plot(r, dt)
plt.show()
```

The solution function is becoming very costly for large amounts of iterations in the simulation:

*(iterations (x) vs time in seconds (y))*

[image: cost function]

Is there a more efficient method of calculating this? I have considered including the 'par_val' in the child df, but I was trying to avoid this as the very large amount of repetitions reduces the amount of simulations I can fit in RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`par_val` is a `float64` which takes 8 bytes for each value. If the child data frame has 1 million rows, that's 8MB of memory (before the OS's Memory Compression feature kicks in). If it has 1 billions rows, then yes, I would worry about the memory impact.

The bigger performance bottleneck though, is in your `df_child.loc[a_mask].apply(..., axis=1)` line. This makes pandas uses the slow Python loop instead of the much faster vectorized code. In SQL, we call the loop approach row-by-agonizing-row and it's an anti-pattern. You generally want to avoid `.apply(..., axis=1)` for this reason.

Here's one way to improve the performance without changing `df_par` or `df_child`:

```py
a_mask = df_child.index.get_level_values('a') == 0

child_val = df_child.loc[a_mask, 'child_val'].droplevel(-1)
solution = df_par.loc[child_val.index, 'par_val'] / child_val
df_child.loc[a_mask, 'solution'] = solution.to_numpy()
```

Before:

[image: row-by-agonizing-row]

After:

[image: vectorized code]